# MySQL: Select top n max values?

Tags: mysql, max

I am really confused about the query that needing to return top N rows having biggest values on particular column.

For example, if the rows `N-1, N, N + 1` have same values. Must I return `just top N` or `top N + 1` rows.

Comment: ORDER BY .. LIMIT, no? If not, please post example data, expected output, and a valid tried (but leading to incorrect results) query.

Comment: ORDER BY just give me top N?

Comment: ORDER BY just orders. The LIMIT supplies the limit. Again, a little bit of example data/results will go a long way (and avoid or reverse downvotes).

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to ask that must I always return top N or if there are some rows have same values (the example), I need to return all of them.

Comment: Groupwise max, with some variants; all efficient:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: This is a pretty efficient method for simple data, just make sure you use a `SEPARATOR` that makes sense for your data in the `GROUP_CONCAT` function call. http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group

Comment: It seems you are asking about requirements. The use case determines how duplicates should be handled. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you do:

```
select *
from t
order by value desc
limit N
```

You will get the top N rows.

If you do:

```
select *
from t join
     (select min(value) as cutoff
      from (select value
            from t
            order by value
            limit N
           ) tlim
    ) tlim
    on t.value >= tlim;
```

Or you could phrase this a bit more simply as:

```
select *
from t join
     (select value
      from t
      order by value
      limit N
    ) tlim
    on t.value = tlim.value;
```

The following is conceptually what you want to do, but it might not work in MySQL:

```
select *
from t
where t.value >= ANY (select value from t order by value limit N)
```

Comment: so with the question "Select top N rows has biggest values", MUST I use the first one or second one. because if I just return the top N, some rows can be missing.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following SQL query.

```
SELECT salary FROM salesperson 
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 2,1
```

Comment: You have to describe a litle bit more. And I don't think this answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use self join for this.

1. first find the top (n) possible values for a perticular column
2. join it with same table based on the primary key

For E.g.  on below sample table

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `ID` INT(11)   AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   `SALARY` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
    JOINING_DATE TIMESTAMP  
) ENGINE=MYISAM 

INSERT INTO  employee (NAME,salary,joining_date)    VALUES('JAMES',50000,'2010-02-02'),
('GARGI',60000,'2010-02-02'),('DAN',30000,'2010-02-02'),('JOHN',10000,'2010-02-02'),('MICHEL',70000,'2010-02-02'),
('STIEVE',50000,'2010-02-02'),('CALRK',20000,'2010-02-02'),('BINNY',50000,'2010-02-02'),('SMITH',40000,'2010-02-02'),
('ROBIN',60000,'2010-02-02'),('CRIS',80000,'2010-02-02');
```

With the above table-data set up **Query to find employees having top 3 salaries**  would be   :

```
SELECT e1.* FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 3 ) S1
JOIN employee  e1 
ON e1.salary = s1.salary 
ORDER BY e1.salary DESC
```

**TIP:-**

If you need top 4 then just change `LIMIT 3`  to `LIMIT 4`

Comment: In your example query you are referring to the same table with different cases (S1/s1). This doesn't work, as noted in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). But otherwise the answer is great, thank you.

Comment: I tested it on WIndows at that time . Thanks for suggestions yep I should have used the same case at both places s1/S1