# most simple "return highscores" SQL Query using userID

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

High there

working at a minimal game on Android I get lost when it comes to sql queries.

I'm trying to get a top 100 ranking list and it almost works but not quite

I am using this query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WorldGames_table GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100";
```

the thing is that it returns a list of the top 100 scores, in the proper order and containing only 1 score of each user. But it is not always the best score of the users that is shown.

I am getting completely confused by the way complexes queries are "organised", that is why I am looking for a simple query

cheers

**UPDATE**: Solved (or so I though at the time :s)

this is the line that returns what i was looking for :D

```
SELECT WorldGames_table .*, MAX(score) as score FROM WorldGames_table GROUP BY id, device_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Thanks to AT-2016 and to every one who gave a hand :D

**UPDATE II**: not solved after all :S

So happy that the proper Highscores were showing up in the ranking, I didn't realise that, actually, with this query *All the scores from each user are showing up*, instead of returning only the best score of each user.
Here I go again, in the search of the most simple "return highscores" SQL Query using userID

**UPDATE III**: I think the answer might come from [this place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)
so I put this together, and again, it works in my local test and fails when a apply it on my server

```
SELECT a.id, a.timestamp, a.name, a.score, a.color, a.flower, a.user_id

FROM games_table a

INNER JOIN (

    SELECT id, MAX(score) score
    FROM games_table
    GROUP BY user_id

) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.score = b.score

ORDER BY a.score DESC

LIMIT 100
```

Still investigating, the piñata way ;)

**UPDATE IV**: I think I have it (but I won't it is done before I'm sur)
In the mean time this is what I found. NOPE, ANOTHER FAILED ATTEMPT :(

I tried my queries directly inside PHPmyAdmin

Found out that  that query

```
SELECT
timestamp, name, MAX(score), color, flower, device_id 

FROM
 WorldFlowers_table 

GROUP BY 
 device_id 

ORDER BY
 score 
 DESC 

LIMIT 100;
```

returned an error message like this:
"Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

So I added "id," at the beginning of line #2

and now it looks like I get the result I was looking for
I did some test but I will make sur it works to mark the question as "answered"

Did not work, now I'm looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column?rq=1) without much hope

The only thing I gained today is that I test the queries directly into phpmyadmin

if there is anyone out there **HELP !**

**UPDATE V**: someone called scaisEdge gave me this answer and, at least until now, it seems to work. Waiting for more testing to say "answered"

```
  select * from WorldFlowers_table
  where  (device_id, score) in (  select device_id, max(score) 
                                  FROM WorldFlowers_table 
                                  GROUP BY device_id  
                                  ORDER BY score DESC 
                                  )
  ORDER BY score DESC 
  LIMIT 100
```

**UPDATE VI**

it works !! :)

and the answer was given to me , like I said above, by scaisEdge, in another "instance" of this question that I posted here
[mySQL "get TOP 100 scores" query is turning me crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833606/mysql-get-top-100-scores-query-is-turning-me-crazy)

Comment: I created a dummy DB on which I run that same query , using a DB Browser, and I get the proper result.
Thing is, with my actual mySQL DB, I get the second (or third...) best score of a particular user_id

Comment: I am not sure what's happening. Try using this - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-nth-highest-record-database-table-using-mysql.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use MAX() to get the highest values:

```
SELECT MAX(Values) FROM WorldGames_table 
GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100
```

Try the below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table JOIN
    (SELECT MIN(Score) as Values -- Or use MAX()
      FROM (SELECT Score
            FROM Table
            ORDER BY Score
            LIMIT 100
           ) Table2
    ) Table2
ON Table.Score >= Table2;
```

Comment: that just returns the highest scores.
I think I need the 
- 1st get the index of the rows that match to this query
- 2nd SELECT all the values of the rows that come in the above list

...or something

Comment: Well! You asked about highest scores for each user and the question was so. Then how do you expect to get it?

Comment: I'm totally swimming in this sql thing for 2 days now. And I guess for such a simple thing like this , it just shows how lost I am :S

- All my users have a unique user_id
- I want only the best "rank/score/name" of each user to appear in the TOP100
- and of course I want the TOP100 to show the 100 Top score in DESC order

What is it that I am making wrong ?

Comment: Check the second one. See if it helps or check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827388/mysql-select-top-n-max-values

Comment: I think it might be it, please, can you help me with the Values ?
The best I can come up with is
|||||||||||
SELECT *
FROM WorldGames_table JOIN
    (SELECT min(value) as Values
      FROM (SELECT VALUE
            FROM WorldGames_table 
            ORDER BY Score
            LIMIT 100
           ) Table2
    ) Table2
    on T.Score >= Table2;
||||||||||||
and I get completely lost with those 2 lines
    (SELECT min(value) as Values
      FROM (SELECT VALUE

Comment: Lost means? Does it work? If not, let me know and if possible, share table structure and sample data. See I could help.

Comment: I cannot get your second code to work because I cannot fill the values (because I cannot see what goes where) (that's "lost" ; ) )
Here you see my db and my result, using my first query
http://rich.gg/assets/SQLdb2.jpg

Comment: OK. Now share an expected output to the specific. It's confusing to see only sample data.

Comment: in the expected output, the second line would show SO-NY 70 Point, since you can see that the row id 260 is the best score for this device ID (blue)

Comment: Then at the end of the query, see writing this - GROUP BY id, device_id DESC LIMIT 100.

Comment: YES !! :D
That's it, it work !
So that was this "id," that was missing
I don't know really how to close the question since this is my first one in here.
I want to say thank you AT and thanks to you you all.
You made my day !

Comment: Great! Glad to know it worked. Don't forget to mark as answer :D

Comment: my php goes like this
//////////////////////
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 array_push($response, array("timestamp"=>$row[1], "name"=>$row[2], "score"=>$row[3], "color"=>$row[4], "flower"=>$row[5], "device_id"=>$row[6]));
 
 }

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

$conn->close();
//////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the sum?

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(score) as sum_score FROM WorldGames_table GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC LIMIT 100";
```

Comment: I get weird stuff with the query you suggested

{"timestamp":null,"name":null,"score":null,"color":null,"flower":null,"user_id":null}

Comment: It is because in my example I just selected the score. You should select SUM(score) as sum_score, timestamp, name, color, flower, user_id as well. Because with a SUM() you cannot select all the other column at the same time.

Comment: I don't believe that OP wants the sum of all the scores by user, he wants the highest score for each user.

Comment: yes, I want the best score of each user.
thing is I get it using my query when I do it in my Dummy SQLite DB
And it doesn't work when I use the same query on mySQL server

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that, I thought each user had points and OP wanted to add every points to get the score. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you well but maybe you need to write your query like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT WorldGames_table.*, MAX(score) as score FROM WorldGames_table GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100";
```

Comment: This one looked very good to me, but , even though it worked on my local DB, it doesn't work on the online DB

Comment: I think you have some another problem on your remote

Comment: any idea of where I should look ?
-
Also in this query:
SELECT * FROM WorldGames_table GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100
-
it looks like I ORDER the result by score, but at no point do I say that I want the group elements to be picked as max value (or do I ) ?

Comment: no it just gives me an older result
like, for instance I should get
#1 TOTO 70
#2 TITI 65
#3 TATA 42

and I get the second best of TITI instead, like this
#1 TOTO 70
#2 TITI 62
#3 TATA 42

If I check in the DB, the 1st best result of TITI is indeed 65

Comment: you have similar data in local and on the server? and you get correct result on local and incorrect result on server?

Comment: not the very same data but similar table.
I made this sample DB, using SQLite on my PC to try figuring out the queries
Problem is It works fine in local so I cannot learn much more

Comment: consider that we have three columns in the table 'game': id, name, score. 

The query should look like: 'SELECT id, name, MAX(score) AS score FROM game GROUP BY name ORDER BY score DESC'

it should work well, I have tested it recently

Comment: I have tried with your code, I get the same output as with mine. like this
http://rich.gg/assets/SQLdb2.jpg