# MySQL Selection for top x rankings

Tags: mysql

I want to make a selection in my `MySQL` database where I have stored numerical values in a specific column.

I have seen some websites that show *10 ten* based on some criteria, and I've been wondering if it will be possible to make a selection based on numerical values.

I have my database like so:

```
| id | name      | pts |
+----+-----------+-----+
| 1  | Brad      |  3  |
| 2  | Jane      |  8  |
| 3  | Jones     |  10 |
| 4  | Paty      |  15 |
| 5  | Sammy     |  2  |
```

Now my question is, how do I make a query that selects only the top 3 users, based on the `pts`, such that it returns the result as:

```
1st Position = Paty => 15pts
2nd Position = Jones => 10pts
3rd Position = Jane => 8pts
```

?

Comment: Have you tried any query? This has been asked multiple times around here and you can find an answer easily. What have you tried before posting? This is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422488/select-first-10-distinct-rows-in-mysql, it has a little different purpose, but It does the same.

Comment: Forgive me, but I couldn't find any. Can you send  a link to duplicates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: Select top N max values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827388/mysql-select-top-n-max-values)

Comment: Any introductory book or tutorial would be useful at this point.

Comment: what if people have the same score?

Comment: Then the query will return the results of the people with the same result. I haven't thought about this tho, but I believe something else will be used to determine the actual positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

`SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY pts desc limit 3`

Answer (score 1):

Your query should use LIMIT to get the top results:

```
SELECT id, name, points FROM table ORDER BY pts DESC LIMIT 3
```

shoul do the trick.

Order by will order the table from the highest to the lowest and limit will tell mysql to get only the first three results

You can find more on this topic here for [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html).
And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit) is a question very close to your

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query

```
SELECT CONCAT(`id` , 'Postion = ' , `name` , '=>' ,`pts` , 'pts' ) AS result FROM table ORDER BY pts DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This Question I seen many places anyway the query is.

`select top 3 * from tablename order by cols_name desc`

This Query brings top 3 row with highest values based on your column.